# hitting limits while creating a unlocked package version

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I run the following command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p SFExtension -d force-app -k xxxx --wait 10 -v DevHub
```

and with my 6th (5 finished successfully) execution I get this error:

```
ERROR:  The package2 version create request failed because this organization has reached its daily limit.
```

What limit does block me here? Can I really only build a package 5 times a day?

...this is really frustrating :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can query the limits by the following command:

```
sfdx force:limits:api:display
```

Run this against your dev hub org, and you'll see a line like this:

```
NAME                                   REMAINING  MAXIMUM
─────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
...
PackageVersionCreates                  50         50
```

This is the daily limit for the **entire org**. If you've run out, you'll have to wait until tomorrow.

The limits are different for different types of orgs, so you'll need to check your org's limits.

Edit:

I couldn't find the chart that I've seen before, but it does seem like Developer Edition is limited to 6 packages/day, Enterprise should be 50/day, and Performance/Unlimited should be 200/day.

A developer edition is really not intended to be a *real* hub, just more of a learning/design/package container. Your dev hub org should be a real (i.e. paid) org.

Comment: many thanks for this, I placed a follow up question, maybe you could help me on this too: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243958/confused-about-the-different-org-types-involved-in-a-salesforce-development-env

Comment: @sfdcfox Is this actually a daily limit? Wouldn't the name start by Daily.... like other limits? (DailyScratchOrgs, DailyStreamingApiEvents, DailyWorkflowEmails)? Would you have some official documentation somewhere ?

Comment: @CloudNinja This answer is old. Here's the relevant quote ([here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_before.htm)): *The maximum number of unlocked package versions that you can create from a Dev Hub per day is the same as your daily scratch org allocation. To request a limit increase, contact Salesforce Customer Support.*

Answer (score 8):

Since spring 20 its possible create a package without validation and the limits are 500 versions

[image: 500 versions]

[image: Link]

Answer (score 5):

Two additional remarks to the answers already given, as I stumbled across them myself:

1. API limits do not reset at midnight because they are count in a rolling 24 hour period.
2. The --skipvalidation parameter does not work for org-dependent unlocked packages. It causes the following error:
   "Can’t create package version. You can’t specify skip validation on an org-dependent unlocked package. Try creating the package version without specifying skip validation."