# confused about the different org types involved in a salesforce development env

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm new to SF development and only need to do some very small stuff for our org (e.g. triggers, custom fields)...

This is our setup:

- we have a productive Salesforce org with a single licence for our company, I call it 'ProdHub' (yes we are very small and share the login)
- I have a salesforce org which I currently use as my 'DevHub' (a free instance which I created for myself)
- I have a salesforce trailhead org which I can use to test/ practice stuff

This is how I see the world for development:

- I create scratch orgs on my DevHub and push/pull my unlocked package
- I execute `sfdx force:package:create` against my DevHub
- I execute `sfdx force:package:version:create` against my DevHub

Now [I face a limit problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243947/hitting-limits-while-creating-a-unlocked-package-version) with `sfdx force:package:version:create` (I can only create 6 packages during a day).

`sfdx force:limits:api:display -u DevHub` tells me:

```
NAME                                   REMAINING  MAXIMUM
─────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
Package2VersionCreates                            6
```

while the same for the production org tells gives me:
`sfdx force:limits:api:display -u ProdHub`

```
NAME                                   REMAINING  MAXIMUM
─────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
Package2VersionCreates                 80         80
```

So I wonder if I should just do all development in our production env? I'm very confused about where I can and where I should push/pull stuff and where I should create the final package. I did enable 'Dev Hub' on a my Dev org and on my Prod org (which most likely was a bad mistake, but it seems I can't revert that). 'Enable Packaging' currently is only enabled on my Dev org.

If I'd use my prod org to create the package then I have a much higher limit to create packages, but Is that a good idea? Can I push/pull on my DevHub scratch orgs and only use ProdHub to create the final package? is this a good idea? I guess in this case I would also need to create scratch orgs on my ProdHub, correct?

I'm also confused whether I can push/pull to DevHub or only to scratch orgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your work-based projects, use your production org. For side hobbies, use your Developer org. This will help keep them apart. And, yes, you can only push/pull on scratch orgs, which should also be created from your production org as well. You can use your personal dev hub org for trailheads or other reasons; 6 should be plenty per day in that scenario.